# If your access tokens only have a life of 10-15 minutes or shorter, do you really need to implement refresh tokens?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I am implementing OAuth2/OWIN/Katana Authentication/Authorization with the requirement of the tokens only living for a few minutes with a max of 10, maybe 15. If this is the case, do I need refresh tokens implemented? It is my understanding they are only a benefit for long lasting "sessions"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about a custom implementation. If you are OK with the user being prompted again, then you don't need refresh tokens. Refresh tokens exist so that you can have short lived access tokens that have to be renewed often, giving you an opportunity of revoking them by invalidating the refresh token itself. If you don't need to use tokens beyond that 10, 15 mins timeframe, then you might not need refresh tokens.